# Events Arguments JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, dom-events

I have the follow doubt:

I'm manipuling an activex object from html tag :

`<object classid="clsid:3751B5D4-D348-11D0-AD02-0060970C3D2F" id="sdo_prr" name="sdo_prr" width="0" height="0"></object>`;

And that object return me some events that I get from the following tags:

```
    <script language="javascript" for="sdo_prr" event="AtPrintRawEnd">
        <!--
           I can put some line code in here.
        //-->
    </script>
```

To understand the tag above I will explain yours attributes:

When I put the attribute `for="sdo_prr"`, I want to say that this script is connected directly to my subject matter.

When I put the attribute `event`, I want to say that this script is waiting for the event for the object, i.e., this script will be executed when the object in question to fire this event `AtPrintRawEnd`.

Now is my question:
This event he has an argument in which I need to get it, just as I get an argument from an event in C# for example: `EventArgs e`.

Comment: To clarify, what is the event you are waiting on and what would you like to execute once this event occurs?

Comment: Sooo, I Waiting for the event "AtPrintRawEnd" that is specific event for my object! And thhis event have some arguments, you know? can you understand me?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your event this way instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var obj = document.getElementById('sdo_prr');
  obj.attachEvent('AtPrintRawEnd', function(arg1) {
    // event handler here
  }​​)​;
</script>
```

I'm not sure that it will work, but I am pretty sure there is no way to get at the arguments with the other pattern.

Comment: the attributes could be accessed like any other html attribute, but they're invalid for the element, so they shouldn't be used.

Comment: OP doesn't want the attributes, he wants the arguments and those attributes are legal for IE which is the browser in question if ActiveX is being used. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535892(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

People thanks for all comments...
I found the solution by the follow way:

I pass the argument set the event named in the event within the event tag;;